# Dynamic switching of DB in JBoss

Tags: java, jboss

Is it possible to switch DB dynamically in JBoss(Either loading XML or switching to another DataSource)? If so then how?

Comment: I mean without restarting server i need to switch DB

Comment: can you give some details.what you are using.etc

Comment: @bilash.saha : JBoss application server, Oracle 9i DB where we have different schemas(I need to switch between two DataSource). Sorry I was wrong not DB just DataSource.

Comment: Do You have the DS file in deploy directory?

Comment: @bilash.saha :Sorry to ask. what is DS file? where and how can i find that?

Comment: Well DS means Datasource File, have a extension like '-ds.xml'.By which you are connecting to database

Comment: @bilash.saha : ya we have that xml file. I have defined 2 DataSources as of now. How to look up that dynamically?

Comment: you should define one datasource at a time.Now read my answer carefully.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4919/discussion-between-bilash-saha-and-john-solomon)

Comment: @bilash.saha : yes, jboss-xa-jdbc.rar is there in my deployment directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JBoss deploy directory contains the hot-deployable services (those which can be added to or removed from the running server). It also contains applications for the current server configuration. You deploy your application code by placing application packages (JAR, WAR and EAR files) in the deploy directory. The directory is constantly scanned for updates, and any modified components will be re-deployed automatically.

So at runtime if you change the Datasource file.It will be re-deployed automatically.And you will get the changed effect without restarting the server.

Comment: While i changed the DS file. Following exception came in server console. It first unbound my datasource after that it rebound the same.                                                                         
org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: You are trying to use a connection factory that
has been shut down: ManagedConnectionFactory is null.; - nested throwable: (javax.r
esource.ResourceException: You are trying to use a connection factory that has been
 shut down: ManagedConnectionFactory is null.)

Comment: Here is the detailed log:-                                  18:21:17,198 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Unbound ConnectionManager 'jbo
ss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=SAGDataSource' from JNDI name 'SAGDataSource'
18:21:18,057 INFO  [WrapperDataSourceService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:se
rvice=DataSourceBinding,name=SAGDataSource' to JNDI name 'SAGDataSource'
18:21:58,944 WARN  [iLogistics] <Session null> <Class 'com.ibsplc.ilogistics.system
.jobscheduler.timer.dao.sql.TimerSqlDAO'>null
org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: You are trying to use a connection factory...

Answer (score 1):

You can, by touching the -DS.xml file in your deploy directory, the scanner will re-deploy the Data source descriptor. I wonder whey you would want to do this though? If you are 'swtiching' between two databases, why don't you just deploy the descriptors for the two databases?? either in one -DS.xml file, or as two seperate -DS.xml files ? Or, are you saying you are using a JPA persistence called 'XXX' which refers to two different DB's.